# How to remove support library (appcompat_v7) [Eclipse]

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've updated my eclipse and ADT Plugin to the latest version recently and recognised some big changes. Whenever I create a new Android Application Project there appears a new appcompat_v7 library which wasn't present before and also a fragment_main.xml . Why is that? Why is the activity_main.xml file not preferred for activity layout directly anymore and why appcompat library is now included in every project ? I tried to remove eclipse/adt/sdk many times and remove the support library from sdk manager but got no result !  I realize it has something to do with actionbar but the problem is that whenever I create a new project a red exclamation mark shows up on both project's file and appcompat_v7 file and this prevents me from compiling/running the application or even sometimes appcompat_v7 file doesn't create and the only thing I get is damaged code here's a picture :https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJMfW.png

so how can I remove this dependency and thanks

Comment: Note : If I remove the damaged code "that's shown in the picture" I get an error : R cannot be resolved to a variable and importing R creates more errors .

Comment: Try right-clicking and selecting delete. I noticed this same annoyance, and you can delete the unnecessary files (fragment.xml/.java) and edit the manifest targets accordingly. Then make sure you create a "skeleton" that you can just drag and drop into future new projects that suit your needs.

Comment: it does not even look like you imported the library

Comment: I didn't import It ! I don't even know where it came from @tyczj

Comment: @SQLiteNoob If I remove the fragment and remove the extra code that belongs to actionbar in Mainactivity.java I get R cannot be resolved to a variable etc .. This problem drove me mad since I have been looking for a solution for days

Comment: It's not an import, Eclipse/SDK implements it by force after the last update. They are trying to force conformity (which is fine) but it doesn't help apps made for testing.

Comment: @user3472788 did you try cleaning/building the project? Work from memory or look at old apps and see what the base files are, and try to start with just the basic old setup.

Comment: Hello,Thank you all for helping me . I've already solved the problem .

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> Why is that?

Because Google engineers added that stuff to the new-activity templates, for at least the "BlankActivity".

> Why is the activity_main.xml file not preferred for activity layout directly anymore

You are certainly welcome to use `activity_main.xml` for whatever you want. It so happens that Google's current templates want you to use fragments. Google's templates are just templates. One can argue -- and I have, vehemently -- that a "BlankActivity" template should not be doing what it is doing. However, beyond that, it is just a template.

> why appcompat library is now included in every project ?

Presumably, they wanted to start you off with a consistent action bar, even on older API levels.

> I realize it has something to do with actionbar but the problem is that whenever I create a new project a red exclamation mark shows up on both project's file and appcompat_v7 file and this prevents me from compiling/running the application or even sometimes appcompat_v7 file doesn't create and the only thing I get is damaged code

I reported [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67513) a week or so ago.

> so how can I remove this dependency

Step #1: Right-click over the project name in the Package Explorer, and choose Properties. Click on Android in the list of property categories on the left, and scroll down on the right to the bottom:

[image: Eclipse Project Properties, Android Category]

Step #2: In the list of attached library projects that you will now see in the properties dialog, you may see an entry akin to the "appcompat_v7_6" one that you see in the above screenshot. Your last digit will differ, and it may be that yours has a red X instead of a green checkmark. Regardless, if there is an entry for "appcompat_v7_NNN" in the list, click on it, then click the Remove button to the right of the list. Then, click the OK button to close up the dialog.

Step #3: In `res/values/styles.xml`, change the parent of `AppBaseTheme` from `Theme.AppCompat.Light` to `@android:style/Theme.Light`. In `res/values-v11/styles.xml`, change the parent of `AppBaseTheme` from `Theme.AppCompat.Light` to `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light`. In `rest/values-v14/styles.xml` change the parent of `AppBaseTheme` from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` to `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`. Note that these values assume that you chose the default "Light theme with dark action bar" when you created the project -- you will need to make slight adjustments to those instructions for anything else.

Step #4: In `res/menu/main/xml`, remove `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` from the root `<menu>` element and the `app:showAsAction="never"` attribute from the `<item>` element.

Step #5: In your activity (e.g., `MainActivity`), change the parent class of the activity to something other than `ActionBarActivity` -- `FragmentActivity` would be a good choice, to minimize the number of other changes you will have to make immediately. Also, clean your imports (e.g., <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-O</kbd>).

At this point, other than perhaps cleaning your project (Project > Clean from the main menu), the `appcompat` stuff should be ripped out of a project created using the "BlankActivity" template and with a "Navigation Type" of "None". Other templates, or navigation options on the "BlankActivity" template, will probably require more work.

Comment: Hello sir , Thank you for your time . As I can see this solution takes much time specifically because I create a lot of projects . I've already formatted my PC and installed eclipse/sdk again and now the appcompat works , but the only downside that I can't place elements in GUI freely "The position" using drag and drop , so can you think of a solution ? I'll anyway create new question for this issue but well that's better than nothing .

Comment: I'd upvote this one 5 times too. Spent hours trying to get a solution. The least they could've done was adding an option to exclude appcompat, with a very bold warning.

Comment: What is meant by last paragraph.?
I'm getting all red red errors in my MainActivity file.

Comment: @HarshitGupta: You have problems in some resources and/or the manifest.

Comment: Thanks for your great solution, now for adding an activity Should I use "Empty Activity"?

Comment: @SirwanAfifi: `EmptyActivity` is a reasonable starting point, at least if your `minSdkVersion` is 11 or higher. I haven't tried it recently on something old enough where the tools might try adding in `appcompat_v7`.

Comment: I just say "Love you Stackoverflow, I am nothing without you" :)

Answer (score 7):

***Best ways to solve these:***

1. Firstly in project,`Right click->properties->Android`.There you can
   see the `red marked appcompat` placed in `Reference`. Click that and
   Remove it.
2. Delete **fragment_main.xml** and **Appcompat** file created in your *Eclipse*.
3. Edit and change your **activity_main.xml** like these:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@string/hello_world" />

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
4. In **res/values/styles.xml:**

   ```
   <resources>

       <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">

       </style>

       <!-- Application theme. -->
       <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

       </style>

   </resources>
   ```
5. In **res/values-v11/styles.xml** you have to change like these:

   ```
   <resources>

       <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
       </style>

   </resources>
   ```
6. In **res/values-v14/styles.xml** you have to change like these:

   ```
     <resources>

       <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
       </style>

       <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
       </style>

   </resources>
   ```
7. Change your **menu/main.xml** like these:

   ```
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

       <item
           android:id="@+id/action_settings"
           android:orderInCategory="100"
           android:showAsAction="never"
           android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

   </menu>
   ```
8. Finally change your **MainActivity.java** like these:

   ```
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;


   public class MainActivity extends Activity {


       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   }

   }
   ```

LikeWise you have to do it for creating a new project