# Android ADT Bundle Creates appcompat and I don't what

Tags: android, eclipse

I downloaded the ADT Bundle directly from android website for my mac. Everything was fine until I created a new project, and eclipse created my project as well as a folder named "appcompat_v7".

But I don't it, because that way I can't follow the tutorial, since you can't extend a method more than 1 time for example:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

What can I do ? I can't follow any tutorial. I was trying this one (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E780gbh6vLU) and I can't because I have that appcompat_v7 project. The same happens with this one (http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-barcode-reader--mobile-17162)

Please I really need help, for my university project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261288/why-eclipse-automatically-adds-appcompat-v7-library-support-whenever-i-create-a

Comment: I hope this one will help. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769016/how-to-remove-support-library-appcompat-v7-eclipse

Comment: I'll try each one of them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it extend `Activity` and use the android.app.* versions of various classes (Activity, Fragment, etc) instead. IN your styles.xml, make your base style extend an Android-provided theme (like Theme.Holo) instead of the AppCompat one.